# can dropbox synchronize only specific files in an xcode project?

Tags: xcode, dropbox

I am working on an Xcode project with a few other developers. I would like to know if there is a way that I can update only specific files of an xcode project so that I'll only make changes to those classes anytime I synchronize the project in dropbox.

Comment: I would seriously consider github or Bitbucket (free private repos), or any of these: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/18/the-top-7-open-source-version-control-systems/ over Dropbox for development work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, Dropbox doesn't do that.

You should still be able to use Dropbox source control. Here's how.

1. Create your project using Git in Xcode. Save the project *outside* of your Dropbox folder.
2. Copy your project from the original location into Dropbox (you now have 2 copies).
3. Open the original project (the one outside Dropbox) in Xcode.
4. Open up the **Organizer** and go to **Repositories**.
5. Click on "Remote" section of your project.
6. Click the "Add Remote" button.
7. Fill in the location field using file:// and the directory path the one in Dropbox
8. Now just push and pull changes to the remote repository as needed.

Just because you can do it though... doesn't mean you should. You get a free account from [ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com) which includes Git repositories and bug tracking software. It is still your private data, with full permission sets for access.